# how to combine data from two table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

See I have two tables like

Table1:TheaterDetail

```
t_id    t_Address    t_Name   c_id
1       ahmedabad    Cinemax1   1
2       Baroda       Cinemax2   2
3       Jamnagar     Cinemax3   3
4       Rajkot       Cinemax4   4
5       Surat        Cinemax5   5
6       Junagadh     Cinemax2   2
```

Table2:CityDetails

```
c_id    City_name
1       Ahm
2       Bar
3       Jam
4       Raj
5       Sur
```

I want Out Put Like That is it possible? I am new to sql so i found its hard.
I want column name to be display in output (t_address,t_name)

```
Ahm 
t_address   t_name
ahmedabad   Cinemax1
Bar 
t_address   t_name
Baorda  Cinemax2
Junagadh Cinemax2
Jam 
t_address   t_name
Jamnagar    Cinemax3
Raj 
t_address   t_name
Rajkot  Cinemax4
Sur 
t_address   t_name
Surat   Cinemax5
```

I do Two query Like These

```
 select distinct city_name from CityDetail A inner join TheaterDetail B

    on A.c_id = B.c_id where a.c_id= 2

   city_name
   Bar
```

And Other Query Like this

```
select t_Address,t_Name from TheaterDetail C inner JOin CityDetail D
on C.c_id = D.c_id where D.c_id= 2

t_Address   t_Name
Baroda      Cinemax2
Junagadh    Cinemax2
```

My desire Out put will be like this if i put condition on city_id=2

```
Bar 
t_address   t_name
Baorda      Cinemax2
Junagadh    Cinemax2
```

Comment: Sure it's possible, but it's better to handle this kind of layout in the presentation layer.

Comment: presentation layers mean?
I m using simple asp.net gridview control to display the output of same..

Comment: It would be better to use a repeater in asp.net, and as you loop through the rows of data, if the city changes, add a row with just the City name, and then another row with the column headers, and then proceed to add the data rows until the city changes again.

Comment: ya ya you are right we can use repeater control instead of gridview.
but for this i also need to create dataset so i would appriciate if you can help me to create query for that

Comment: @Sanjay why don't you try the query you posted as the query for your repeater?

Comment: Your second query in your question will work fine if you add the City_name to the select list and take out the WHERE condition.

Comment: according to your solution i will get two diffrent row for city "BAR" and for each city row i get t_address and t_name but i acctually want to display two t_address under one city

Comment: i got the solution for that I create two diffrent query and i use nested gridview for these two queris and after that bind the two gridview with those queires

Comment: is there any option available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will be the query you want

```
    drop table Tbl1
    Create table Tbl1
    (
        iSrno int identity(1,1) not null,
        c_id numeric(18,2),
        city_name nvarchar(500) 
        ,t_name nvarchar(500)
    )

    Insert into Tbl1 
    select c_id,city_name as city_name, '' as t_name from CityDetails
    Union
    select c_id, 't_address','t_name'  from CityDetails

    Insert into Tbl1 
    select b.c_id,a.t_address,a.t_name  from TheaterDetail as a 
    Inner join CityDetails b on a.c_id= b.c_id

select * from Tbl1 Order by c_id asc , iSrno asc
```